# Polylines going off the map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to show a broad view of the globe with several markers scattered with polylines connecting them. My map's view is locked so one can't rotate/zoom/pan/move or anything like that. Look at this screenshot:

http://gyazo.com/b81336ff514d76e95ac721aa5381d6c1

The polylines merely take the shortest route which in this case, involves going off the map. I want the lines to all go across the center of the map. Is there a way to do this within the API?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect it you must take a look at the longitudes of the 2 points of the path.

When one longitude is greater than 0 and the other is smaller than 0 **and** the difference between both longitudes is greater than 180 you must add an additional point in the middle of the path.

Sample-code:

```
       //path is an array of 2 LatLng's
        if(
            ((path[0].lng()>=0)!=(path[1].lng()>=0))
              &&
            (Math.abs(path[0].lng())+Math.abs(path[1].lng())>=180)){
            console.log(123)
          path=[  path[0],
                  new google.maps.LatLng((path[0].lat()+path[1].lat())/2,
                                         (path[0].lng()+path[1].lng())/2),
                  path[1]]
        }
```

Comment: Yep, this worked. I was aware of a solution involving adding another point to the polyline's path. I was just wondering if there was some method or option I could use from the API that would accomplish the same thing. Nonetheless, thanks anyways.